# Multiply matrices using dgemv and multithreads in c

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a problem in my code. I want to multiply 2 matrices using dgemv from cblas, but I want to share the operations to the threads I have. I have also used dgemv to multiply the matrices in a previous exercise where there was no parallelism needed. Is there any idea of what I should do?

The code:

```
for (it = 0; it < itime; it++) {
    cblas_dgemv(CblasColMajor,CblasNoTrans,n,n, 1 , sigma, n, u , 1, 0.0 , d, 1);
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,sum) schedule(static)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {       
        sum = 0.0;
        uplus[i] = u[i] + dtmu - dt * u[i];
        #pragma omp simd reduction(+:sum)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            sum += sigma[i*n+j]*u[j];
        }
        sum = sum - u[i]*m[i];
        uplus[i] += dtdiv * sum;

        if (uplus[i] > uth) {
            uplus[i] = 0.0;
            if (it >= ttransient) {
                omega1[i] += 1.0;
            }
        }   
    }
    t = u;
    u = uplus;
    uplus = t;
}
```

I want to get the `dgemv` function into the parallel region and share somehow the multiplications to the threads I have.

Comment: Sharing the relevant code is a very good idea.

Comment: I posted the relevant code below